# Создание новых листов Excel (Java) (Apache POI)

Tags: java, swing, excel, apache-poi

При записи из JTable в Excel постоянно создается новый файл с xls, вместо создания новых листов.
К примеру :

Есть 5 листов в excel таблице.

Программа строит JTable на основе этой таблицы.

И нужно чтобы при изменении в JTable все данные сохранялись обратно в Excel-таблицу.

В моём коде происходит следующее :
каждый лист открывается в новом окне.
но по нажатию клавиши сохранить в xls файле стираются все листы,создается текущий лист и сохраняются данные. А нужно чтобы он перезаписывал данные в одном из существующих листов.

Весь код работает на Apache POI, но данный участок кода работает с JXL

```
WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\result.xls"));
                WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet(list, listnum);
                TableModel model = table.getModel();

                for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    Label column = new Label(i, 0, model.getColumnName(i));
                    sheet1.addCell(column);
                }
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        Label row = new Label(j, i + 1,
                                model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                        sheet1.addCell(row);
                    }
                }
                workbook1.write();
                workbook1.close();
```

как исправить код,чтобы конвертировать его из JXL для Apache POI?

В первой строке нужно изменить не на создание новой книги,а чтение уже существующей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в коде должна быть одна книга:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/путь/к/файлу"));
```

на которой создаются новые листы:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
```

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: в вопросе указал код с jxl, как сделать код для Apache poi судя по вашему комментарию?

Comment: [здесь](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide#NewSheet) есть примеры